# The return type 'Object?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In the past you could use a FutureBuilder like this:

```
FutureBuilder(
       future: test(),
       builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.data;
      },
    ),
  test() async {
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref('achtergrond.jpg')
          .getDownloadURL();
      print(downloadURL);
    }
```

Since the latest update it has changed and is now invalid to use. The error message I'm getting  is:

> The return type 'Object?' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the
> closure's context.

So my question is why they it changed it and how to fix it and get data from a function in Dart like you normally would

Comment: snapshot.data bind with widget

Comment: And how are you going to do that?

Comment: Using Text widget or others you need to show your data

Comment: Something like `test() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('achtergrond.jpg')
      .getDownloadURL();
  print(downloadURL);

  return Text('Hi');
}` the thing is that doesn't quite work... Could you show me some code maybe?

Comment: Thanks I for your help I found it!

Comment: You should not be building the Future as part of the future: parameter to FutureBuilder.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever come across this problem this is how to do it:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: test(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            var data = snapshot.data as Widget; // Get the data as a Widget and works just fine
            return data;
          },
        ),
test() async {
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  String downloadURL = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref('achtergrond.jpg')
      .getDownloadURL();
  print(downloadURL);

  return Text(downloadURL);
}
```